# Prove that if the sum of $n$ positive real numbers $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n \le 0.5$, then $(1-x_1)(1-x_2)*...*(1-x_n) \ge 0.5$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

So, I know this could be written as $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n \le 0.5 \le (1-x_1)(1-x_2)*...*(1-x_n)$.

And that the larger $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$ is, the smaller $(1-x_1)(1-x_2)*...*(1-x_n)$ is.

Therefore we could assume that in the worst case scenario $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 0.5$, where one of the x's is close to 0.5, and the rest are close to 0, and then $(1-x_1)(1-x_2)*...*(1-x_n) = 0.5$.

But that's hardly proper proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0<a,b$, then $$(1-a)(1-b)=1-a-b+ab>1-(a+b)  $$
Hence, as all factors are positive,
$$ (1-x_1)\cdots(1-x_{n-1})(1-x_n)>(1-x_1)\cdots(1-x_{n-2})(1-(x_{n-1}+x_n))$$
and by induction 
$$ (1-x_1)\cdots(1-x_{n-1})(1-x_n)>1-(x_x+\ldots +x_n))$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use *Bernoulli's inequality*:

> If $h_1, h_2,\dots, h_n>-1$ and they all have the same sign, then 
>   $$(1+h_1)(1+h_2)\dotsm (1+h_n)\ge 1+h_1+h_2+\dots+h_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ and $x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n$.

Hence, it's obvious that $f$ is a concave function.

Thus, by Karamata $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ln(1-x_i)\geq(n-1)f(0)+f\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\geq\ln\frac{1}{2}$

and we are done!